# How do I download the Windows 10 1511 ISO without using the Media Creation Tool?

Tags: iso-image, windows-10-v1511

For some reasons, I cannot run the Media Creation Tool due to company policy. How can I download the windows 10 Threshold 2 ISO otherwise?

There seems to be a link [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) that has it, but visiting it redirects me to another page.

Cached copy of the webpage in question:

[Here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:yFWPDQgZOI8J:https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=sg)

Comment: Are you connected to a domain and/or running Windows 10 Enterprise.  If you are connected to a domain if you perform the update you will remove your workstation from the domain because of the installation process of the update.  If you are running an Enterprise version of Windows 10 then only your Network Administrator can install the fromt the `Volume License Service Center`.

Comment: There are currently 4 ways to get the Windows 10 Version 1511 update.  I talk about those options in the answer to [this](http://superuser.com/questions/1000240/windows-10-update-1511-failed-and-no-longer-offered/1000252#1000252) question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It's here, try it](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench)
Download 32 or 64 bit ISO, all languages available.
Hashes are verified against MSDN's ISOs. All match.

UPDATE: ^^^ became obsolete, but... There must be a way :-). Use browser, which can change user agent. I use Firefox with User Agent Switcher addon. Set Your browser user agent to

*Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android 6.0.1; Nokia; Lumia 520) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.82 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14348*

and [click here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO/) now select which ISO to download and here You go.

UPDATE2:

for people who writes "it doesn't work for me" in comments.
I just checked it works perfectly. Idea is not to set exactly the same user agent I typed, but to use user agent of OS which Media Creation Tool does not support, for example Linux.

[image: user agent settings]

[image: proof it works]

Comment: Just so the author knows, if they are running Windows 10 Enterprise, the .iSO on the Testbench website won't work.  They will have to download the .ISO from the [Volume Licensing Service Center](https://www.microsoft.com/licensing/servicecenter/default.aspx) instead.

Comment: This answer is obsolete.

Comment: updated an answer.

Comment: Not working anymore.

Comment: works for me with different user agent.

Answer (score 1):

The link provided in your question is allowing you to download an **.iso** file. I test it you can check the screenshot.

[image]

You just have to select the edition and confirm, then select your language (English International.) You get the options to download 64-bit or 32-bit.

The link expires in 24 hours.

Here, I'm adding the link in case you check the answer within 24 hours:
 https://software-download.microsoft.com/pr/Win10_1607_EnglishInternational_x64.iso?t=f5c4b9c1-0c35-4d69-8132-12712f6ca7ac&e=1488956394&h=383c6c87d6215e97fa8f409881d3c421

Comment: While technically correct, there is a requirement for this to work: Your operating system (as reported by the browser) MUST NOT support the Media Creation Tool. It will fall back gracefully to the ISO download page. One can easily reach this page by “forging” the User Agent string to say OS X or Linux or anything really that’s not Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run your browser in Windows 7 compatability mode and download the ISO from Microsofts website.