# Download an ISO for a different edition of Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, iso-image

I'm working on a laptop running Windows 10 Home.  I'd like to take advantage of the fast internet connection I'm on to download an ISO of Windows 10 Professional to install later on another machine.  The [Windows 10 media installation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) doesn't offer the option for Professional, only Home.

The [TechBench page in the solution to this similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1002105/how-do-i-download-the-windows-10-1511-iso-without-using-the-media-creation-tool) doesn't seem to exist any longer.

[image: Screenshot of Media Creation Tool edition selection]

I disagree @magicandre1981 that my question is a [duplicate of this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-the-windows-10-anniversary-update-build-14393).  The answer to this post is no longer valid - the solution link ending 'Windows10ISO' now redirects to the media creation tool, and it was apparent from my question that I already knew of the creation tool's existence.  My question related to confusion as to the availability of Windows 10 Pro through this tool.  The user interface in the previous question has since been redesigned (in a bad way) - I notice it used to say 'Windows 10 editions below are valid for both Windows 10 Home and Windows 10 Professional'.  If it still said that in the media creation tool, my question wouldn't have arisen.

Comment: That version you see in your image contains both Windows Home and Windows Pro - as I mentioned in my answer, you select version on installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ISO provided in the media installation tool should contain both Pro and Home in the same ISO - you select version during installation. Unless this has changed... Otherwise, open your browser in Windows XP compatability (firefox is good for this), and browse to the "Download Windows 10 ISO" site with that. You can then select your version and download the ISO directly

Comment: Thank you. Could you clarify which site is referred to by "Download Windows 10 ISO site"?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows10

or you can just google "Download Windows 10 ISO"

Comment: Confirming that the 'Windows 10' option in the media creation tool does in fact refer to a package of 4 editions that you can choose from at the time of install.  These are:  * Windows 10 Pro  * Windows 10 Home   * Windows 10 Home Single Language  * Windows 10 Education.  It would of course be helpful if Microsoft made this clear in the tool, and makes you wonder why a separate option for 'Windows 10 Home Single Language' is necessary.